# Mapping ICollection to IEnumerable using automap issue

Tags: entity-framework, automapper, asp.net-web-api

Stuck on a strange issue, that works using my get method but fails when returning iqueryable. Some limitation when using projection or iqueryable?
My code looks like below, simplified:

```
    public class SimpleEntity
    {
            public long Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public virtual SimpleEntity Parent { get; set; }
            public virtual ICollection<SimpleEntity> Children { get; set; }

            public SimpleEntity()
            {
                Children = new List<SimpleEntity>();
            }
    }

    public class SimpleEntityResponseDTO
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public NameValueItem ParentReferral { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<NameValueItem> ChildReferrals { get; set; }

        public NavigationFolderResponseDTO()
        {
            ChildReferrals = new List<NameValueItem>();
        }
    }

    public class NameValueItem
    {
        public long Value { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

The web api actions:

```
        [HttpGet, Queryable]
        public IQueryable<SimpleEntityResponseDTO> List()
        {
                //Generic crudservice returning an iqueryable based on Set<SimpleEntity>
                return _crudService.QueryableList().Project().To<SimpleEntityResponseDTO>();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseMessage Get(long id)
        {
            SimpleEntity result = _crudSrv.Get(id);
            if (result != null)
                return Request.CreateResponse<SimpleEntityResponseDTO>(HttpStatusCode.OK, Mapper.Map<SimpleEntity , SimpleEntityResponseDTO>(result));
            else
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound); 
        }
```

And now the mapping:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<SimpleEntity, SimpleEntityResponseDTO>()
                .ForMember(to => to.ParentReferral, opt => opt.MapFrom(from => new NameValueItem { Name = from.Parent.Name, Value = from.Parent.Id }))
                .ForMember(to => to.ChildReferrals, opt => opt.MapFrom(from => from.Children.Select(o => new NameValueItem {Name = o.Name, Value = o.Id}).ToList() ));
```

The parent mapping works no matter what. But the Children mapping is causing below issue.

When retrieving an object through the get method everything works, no matter wich entity i retrieve. When using List i get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object", "d__b.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n". Tried for example adding $filter=Id eq 5 (or whatever id) but results in same issue. Perhaps someone can hint me to what goes wrong here?

Comment: Noticed that when all entities have 0 children then the above works. But as soon as a child is set, then it throws errors.

Comment: It seems like its the projection and output to iqueryable that breaks this.

[HttpGet, Queryable]
        public List<TResponseDto> List()
        {
            using (_profiler.Step("API - Fetching IQueryable list"))
            {
                var res = _crudSrv.QueryableList();
                return Mapper.Map<IQueryable<SimpleEntity>, List<SimpleEntityResponseDTO>>(res);
            }
        } 

The above code makes the solution work, including odata paramaters. But uncertain if this means performance drawbacks.

Question is how to get around this. Project projecting entity props?

Comment: Pinned it down to something i do wrong (or functionality limited?) when mapping to  another complex type using Automapper.QueryableExtensions Project().

Should mention that the parent mapping didnt work propperly either.

If i replace NameValueItem for Parent with a long? and added a mapping like this it sworks for example:
Mapper.CreateMap<SimpleEntity, long?>().ConvertUsing(source => source.Id);

The above is actually enough for my purpose, but if anyone know where im going wrong i would be glad for the input.